# Using Variable Fonts in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, extrafont

I wish to use a Windows 10 font (I am using Windows 10 and the font is installed/usable in other applications like Word) in a `ggplot`.

I am attempting to use the `extrafont` package.

```
library(extrafont)
font_import()
loadfonts(device = "win")
```

Calling `View(fonttable())` shows that Window's fonts have been loaded.

The font I am looking for is called "Bahnschrift Light". The parent font family "Bahnschrift" has been imported, but not the specific font.

I navigated to the Windows fonts folder.  The folder contains the font family "Bahnschrift" but not for the font "Bahnschrift Light". If I double click on the "Bahnschrift" font, a list of (what I believe are) subfamilies, including "Bahnschrift Light".

[Deleted content]

**EDIT:**
I have learned more about this font, now. "Bahnschrift" is a "Variable Font". Variable fonts have one or more axes of variation (weight, width, slant, etc.) that are used to define entire font families in a single font file. [1](https://creativemarket.com/blog/what-is-a-variable-font)
So I can reword my question.

**How/can one use variable fonts in R (specifically in ggplot)?**